# Kafka ACL: performance and memory impact

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, acl

I have Kafka service running in production, I am using kafka ACL default authorizer, ACLs created are saved in Zookeeper.

Currently I have around **500 users** using kafka service, And for each user I am adding around **2 ACL rules** using kafka.acl.sh, it works fine.

But I am worried as the users are going to be increased, lets say when user count becomes **1 Million**, then I may be having **2 Million ACL rules** added to Zookeeper(2 rules for 1 user).

Will this cause any problem? in terms of performance/memory anyway to kafka/zookeeper?

Thanks!

Comment: At that level of users, it might make sense to use Kerberos or Ranger to externalize the authorization management

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, what problem it would cause with current setup? any idea?

Comment: I haven't used the SimpleAuthorizer, but I was under the impression you needed to restart the brokers everytime you added new ACLs, so that in itself would be costly.

Comment: No, as the ACLs are saved in Zookeeper, we dont need to restart brokers when we add new ACLs.